# How to pass data back from ngDialog to caller controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I'm using AngularJS 1.3 and ngDialog 0.5.9

Opening the dialog using the code similar to this:

```
function openDialog() {
    $scope.dataToPassToDialog = myData;
    var dialog = ngDialog.open({
        template: 'template.html',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
        scope: $scope,
    });

    dialog.closePromise.then(function (data) {

    });
}
```

I have a small form in the dialog and I need to pass that data back when user closes the dialog.
Inside dialog controller I'm closing it using :

```
ngDialog.close();
```

I need to pass a data object back from dialog to calling controller, I can't find anything in documentation, I tried

```
ngDialog.close(myDataFromDialog);
```

but I can't access it in any way.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Found how to do it, it's pretty easy, from ngDialog controller I can do

```
$scope.closeThisDialog(dataToPassBack);
```

on the page controller

```
function openDialog() {
    $scope.dataToPassToDialog = myData;
    var dialog = ngDialog.open({
        template: 'template.html',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
        scope: $scope,
    });

    dialog.closePromise.then(function (data) {
        if (data && data.value && /*check if data.value is what you want*/) {
            var dataFromDialog = data.value;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create $scope.myDataFromDialog in your controller

and use it in the dialog

you can find an example in the documentation:

https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog

```
$scope.value = true;

ngDialog.open({
    template: 'externalTemplate.html',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-plain',
    scope: $scope
});

<script type="text/ng-template" id="externalTemplate.html">
<p>External scope: <code>{{value}}</code></p>
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure which controller you referring to in the first line and how to access `$scope.myDataFromDialog`, but I found the answer, thanks anyway